# Using conditional statements in map() in Spark with Java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'd like to use a conditional statement in a map function. For example,

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Long> rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 1, 0)).zipWithIndex();
rdd1.map(x -> if x._1 == 2 return x._1*x._1 else return x._1).foreach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

should print `[(1,0), (4, 1), (1, 2), (0, 3)]`.
So, what's the proper way of using the map function in such way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your code like this :

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Long> rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 1,   0)).zipWithIndex();
rdd1.mapToPair(x -> 
        {
            if (x._1 == 2) 
                return new Tuple2<Integer, Long>(x._1*x._1, x._2); 
            else 
                return new Tuple2<Integer, Long>(x._1, x._2); 
        }).foreach(x -> System.out.println(x));
```

Comment: Thanks! Was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

JavaPairRDD does not define a map() function, but a mapValue() function which can only change the value on a pair and not the key, you could try using another RDD, or, if using that one, don't put values you would want to change in the Key position, but in an Object in the value.